# Installing and setting up MySQL?

Tags: installation, mysql

I have been trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu 10.10 and just can't get it to work. I installed it by running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and once that was done, when I try `mysql` I get the message:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I tried `mysql start` and get the same thing. I am sure I am doing something wrong, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start the mysql demon (or service) you should do:

```
sudo start mysql
```

the old way should still work for now:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

But it's quite strange that mysql didn't start while installing. IIRC, it should be started at the end of the installation and autstarted by default with the system. You can check if the server is running using:

```
ps -A u | grep sql
```

Comment: A slightly more compact way to check if MySQL is running: ps -A | grep mysqld

Answer (score 1):

You can check for mysql startup errors by looking at the log files.  In a terminal, type:

```
tail /var/log/mysql.log
tail /var/log/mysql.err
```

That should let you see the specific errors that are keeping it from running.

Comment: in some versions, you may find mysql errors in /var/log/syslog, too.

Answer (score 0):

To installations of MySQL can specify where we will have the socket for local connections

you have to modify this file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf)

> sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

and add the parameter socket in the section client:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: did you mean `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`